# Component.js not found - when run from XSA launchpad

Tags: sapui5, hana, hana-xs

I have issue with link sapui5 app to the launchpad. I was able to add tile and display it, but when I try to run it, error is logged to the console:

```
Error: failed to load '.../Component.js' from .../Component.js: 404 - Not Found
```

I think that I tried every combination of path (cf.url) and component name placed in "..."

I try to follow tutorial/guide from sap:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/4505d0bdaf4948449b7f7379d24d0f0d/2.0.03/en-US/8a583342d1c64822837fe49efbafdb53.html

but its quite vague and don't provide any answer.

I use namespace `ZApp.sapui` where `sapui` is name of the app.

I believe its only configuration error but I can be wrong.